# AS3 add a border to a displayobject

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, displayobject

I know how to draw a rectangle and add it to a DisplayObjectContainer,
but do you see a simpler method to directly add a border to a DisplayObject?

DisplayObject don't seem to have addChild(), so I would have to add it on the parent, which is not perfect in my opinion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if you're forced to use DisplayObject rather than DisplayObjectContainer then you don't have much choice than to write your border to the parent one way or another.  Agreed though, it's not a nice way of doing things and I think that if it's possible the better approach would be to not use DisplayObject.

Edit: How are you creating this as DisplayObject?  You can't instantiate displayObjects directly, so is this an extension of DisplayObject or the return value of something?

Comment: I produced an external swf, which I linked with Haxe. So it's a MovieClip containing MovieClips and Bitmap... Maybe I need a cast somewhere...

Comment: After verification it should be a MovieClip. I just have to find the way to cast it. Thanks.

Comment: Try `MovieClip(myDisplayObject).doWhateverYouWant()`

Answer (score 3):

I would create a transparent fill shape and add it to the DisplayObject like this:

**Edit** :drawing directly to the DisplayObject

```
this.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
this.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 0);
this.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
this.graphics.endFill();
```

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted to do, but my object is a DisplayObject, so no addChild(). Only DisplayObjectContainer have this :/

Comment: there is no graphics object for DisplayObject: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html

Comment: Graphics is in Sprite, so not available.

Answer (score 2):

a simple way to add a border to something is to use a [Glow Filter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filters/GlowFilter.html):

```
var _objectToBorder:Sprite = new Sprite();
// draw something or add something in the _objectToBorder
var glowFilter:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter(0x000000, 1, 6, 6, 20, 1);
_objectToBorder.filters = [glowFilter];
```

You can play with this [online demo](http://wonderfl.net/c/qitp). Click on the green circle to toggle the glow border.

Keep in mind that using filters can mar performance if used on a ton of items.